# Server side code in both default.aspx and default.aspx.vb - a bad thing?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

We have developers who have permission editing default.aspx.vb, and other people can only edit default.aspx. I found today that we have page_init event exist in both of our aspx and aspx.vb files (with different code in them).

The website is still working as it supposed to be, but I'm just wondering if there were any drawbacks of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, it just makes the application harder to maintain with code so many places. It is best to leave the aspx files for presentation and the .vb files for logic.